# Spring-boot embedded tomcat vulnerabilities compared to standalone

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, tomcat

Is running spring boot java app with embedded tomcat, less vulnerable than running the same version of standalone? In short can we apply the same criteria here?

Comment: The code used in both cases is 99% the same (except a couple of bootstrap classes). The only difference is: with an embedded Tomcat you are responsible for its upgrade and configuration; in the standalone version the user is responsible.

Comment: Is this about an actual embedded system? If not then please don't use that tag.